# Do I need a comma before "particularly"?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Do I need a comma before "particularly" in the case below? Thank you very much for your help!

> Vitamin D has properties against metabolic, neoplastic, and immune disorders **particularly** breast cancer, osteoporosis, and cardiovascular disease.

Comment: Yes. You don't need the comma before *if*, however.

Comment: And arguably it should be 'whether' to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a colon instead of a comma, correct?

Comment: @Doc, not if the word following the colon is "particularly".

Answer (score 3):

> Vitamin D has properties against metabolic, neoplastic, and immune disorders particularly breast cancer, osteoporosis, and cardiovascular disease.

As mentioned, you do need the comma before particularly. However, Vitamin D does not have properties against. It may have **protective effects** against...

We know how it protects against osteoporosis, but not the other disease processes you mentioned.

If you want to keep **properties**, I would say

> Vitamin D has properties **protecting against** metabolic, neoplastic, and immune disorders, particularly breast cancer, osteoporosis, and cardiovascular disease.

Answer (score 1):

> Vitamin D has properties against metabolic, neoplastic, and immune disorders particularly breast cancer, osteoporosis, and cardiovascular disease.

Yes, you need a comma before the *particlarly*. On another note, the phrase "Vitamin D has properties against ..." strikes me as awkward and unwieldy because of the phrase "has properties against". Consider rewording, e.g. "has properties preventing metabolic,...".

Answer (score 0):

This sentence had raised a question in my mind. Vitamin D has **what** property against metabolic, neoplastic and immune disorders..... I think it is better to be specific and clear. May be this sentence can be better rephrased as "Vitamin D has prophylactic/preventive/therapeuti effect against metabolic......"